# Find entity by exact matching in collection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql, spring-repositories

I have entity like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Conversation extends AbstractEntity{

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "conversation_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", nullable = false))
    private List<String> usersIds;
}
```

Is possible to find conversation entity by spring's repository by exact matching of user ids? For instance I have these entities:

```
 id | user_ids
------------------------------------------
 1  | user-a, user-b, user-c
 2  | user-a, user-b
 3  | user-a, user-c
```

So when I will be want found conversation by user ids `user-a` and `user-c` regular IN clause like this:

`SELECT c FROM Conversation c WHERE c.userIds IN :userIds`

will found conversations with id 1 and 3, but I want find exact match, so my expected result is only conversation 3.

Possible solution is use regular IN clause in repository, and next filter collection in service layer but I prefer solution which returns required entity directly from database. Is it possible in JPQL or native sql at least? Thank you.

Comment: Well you are using "IN" which is basically a "subset" operator. Does equals ("=") work? I can't test this right now

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I tried it today and it gives me error on application startup "Operator CONTAINING on usersIds requires a scalar argument"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` with `CASE` to count matched `userId` and check equal with searched `userIds` count.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Conversation c LEFT JOIN c.usersIds cu GROUP BY c "
           + "HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cu IN (:userIds) THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = :userIdsCount")
List<Conversation> findByUserIds(@Param("userIds") List<String> userIds,
                                 @Param("userIdsCount") Integer userIdsCount);
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I was hoping that spring has better support for this use case.

Comment: @DenisStephanov  That is the way you can do using SQL, so for JPQL and I think spring-data-jpa try to support most common uses cases. Exact child match is not the common case in  sql maybe that's why they don't  facilitate any keyword for this.

Comment: the else statement should return 0 instead of -1 ? I think something is wrong with the solution

Comment: @bLaXjack It doesn't matter actually, original task is to match the count or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the user ids in the user_ids column are kept alphabetically ordered. So for example when user b enters the conversation with id 3, the user_ids column that was 'user-a, user-c' becomes 'user-a, user-b, user-c'.

Next make sure that when you want to retrieve a converation based on an exact match of participants, the user ids in the argument to your query is alphabetically ordered as well.
The select can then be

```
select c from Converation c WHERE c.userIds = :userIds
```

Now only exact matches will be found.

Comment: Same answer as I give to Lavish .. it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom query in your Repository class as mentioned below:

```
@Repository
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<ConversationModel, Integer> {

 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select c from Converation c WHERE c.userId = :userId ORDER BY userId DESC LIMIT 1")
    Optional<ConversationModel> findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);

}
```

Now exact matching userId will be getting returned from the database layer. Make it optional and check if the returned value is **not null** while using in the service layer.

For fetching multiple records you'll have to use **IN** in the Query  as mentioned below

```
 @Query("select c from Converation c WHERE c.userIds IN :userIds")
    List<ConversationModel> findByUserIds(@Param("userIds") List<String> userIds);
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Did you tried it? Because it gives me following error: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [cccccccc-000000000001] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [cccccccc-000000000001] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
where cccccccc-000000000001 is one of items in passed collection into repository

Comment: Yes I tried similar query. 


Oh got it, I think since there are multiple entries that your db is returning the method 1 that I mentioned might not be working because it's return type is Optional<ConversationModel>. You might need to limit the result from DB layer then for that you can use something like 

`
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select c from Converation c WHERE c.userId = :userId ORDER BY userId DESC LIMIT 1")
`

Comment: If you check my question there is collection of user ids, not one on conversation entity

Comment: In that case the IN query should have worked. I'm using similar query in my project.