# How to match a list exactly with all values present in JPA Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `User` entity with `skills` property as a type List. I want to query the `User` table against a list of skills in such a way that if all the skills are present in skill column then only a match is found unless no.

I have used JPQL for this but it matches each element in the list one by one using the `IN` clause.

**User Class**

```
@Entity(name = "App_User")
//table name "user" is not allowed in postgres
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "user_email")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email is mandatory")
    private String email;

    //    Current point balance of the user
    @Column(name = "points")
    private int points;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "skills")
    @NotEmpty
    private List<String> skills = new ArrayList();

}
```

JPA query that I have used is

```
SELECT u FROM App_User u JOIN u.skills skill where skill in :skillList
```

If I want to match a list of skills like this `Arrays.asList("skill1","skill2","skill3")`then I want only those users in the result who have all of these skills, not one or two. Above used `IN` clause return the same result.

I have read that it is not possible to compare two lists in JPQL so how can I achieve this using `CriteriaBuilder` `CriteriaQuery`API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.skills sk WHERE sk IN :skillList"
           + " GROUP BY u HAVING COUNT( sk) = :skillListSize")
List<User> findBySkills(@Param("skillList") List<String> skills,
                                 @Param("skillListSize") long skillListSize);
```

Here, group by user and then check group having all skills or not using size. So it will fetch all user having all skills those are given.

Or use this way

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.skills sk GROUP BY u"
           + " HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sk IN (:skillList) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = :skillListSize")
List<User> findBySkills(@Param("skillList") List<String> skills,
                                 @Param("skillListSize") long skillListSize);
```

And if you want a solution for user having exact same skill not more than the given list then see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62664681/4207306).

Comment: Great solution. `Integer skillListSize` need to be updated `Long skillListSize`

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Thanks, by thinking on `skills.size()`  ?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Updated,  actually that's not a problem in a sense when sending value you can make it into integer. (As I don't use `skills.size()` at all)

Comment: I have written a Junit test to verify this by it not showing the expected result. code is here https://pastebin.com/JW6PYevv

Comment: @adarshsrivastava Can you give any example case where it's not working?

Comment: @adarshsrivastava can you show me what query you exactly using ?

Comment: ` @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM App_User u LEFT JOIN u.skills sk WHERE sk IN :skillList"
            + " GROUP BY u HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sk) = :skillListSize")
    List<User> findBySkills(@Param("skillList") List<String> skills,
                            @Param("skillListSize") long skillListSize); `

Comment: Can you try with existing data in database ?. I have small doubt about database insert when test

Comment: @adarshsrivastava I added another solution and remove `Distinct` from 1st solution. Pls check again

Comment: Thank you @Eklavya it works with existing data in database. I was using in-memory DB in test code maybe that's why it was failing.

Comment: @Eklavya Hi, I tried your query but I have a problem if I'm going to add "u" to GroupBy, It going to give me this error: "not a group by expression", I need for a query, If you are avaible to check my question

Comment: @Robs It should work can you post a question about your problem in detail s, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you want to solve is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  u.* FROM App_User u
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT skills FROM App_User WHERE skills IN (list values)
GROUP BY skills
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skills) = (size of list)
) w ON u.user_name = w.user_name
```

Comment: Since we had multiple joins in our query this was the working solution.