# Query entity containing a property of type ArrayList<String>containing a specific set of strings using spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

It is, I think, a stupid question but I am stuck for days on this.
I have an entity with a property to be a List of strings as below:

```
   public class DummyEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @ElementCollection
        private List<String> items;
    }
```

I am using Spring Data JPA and wish to query this entity and fetch from database entities that have an **exact** set of items in that array list. This means if I have in my database:

```
DummyEntity (1, "name1", ["first"])
DummyEntity (1, "name1", ["first", "second"])
DummyEntity (1, "name1", ["first", , "second", "third"])
```

I need a query where I pass i.e. ["first", "second"] (string order is irrelevant) and I get back only DummyEntity (1, "name1", ["first", "second"]). I know that I can do it with java, but I would hate it as work around.

I made for the purpose of the question: [github demo project](https://github.com/arongas/spring-playground.git) where I have a minimal project with a failing test which I need to succeed. What I tried is the following:

```
Page<DummyEntity> findAllByItemsIn(Pageable pageable,List<String> items);
Page<DummyEntity> findAllByItemsContains(Pageable pageable,List<String> items);
Page<DummyEntity> findAllByItemsEquals(Pageable pageable,List<String> items);
Page<DummyEntity> findAllByItems(Pageable pageable,List<String> items);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match a list exactly with all values present in JPA Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733249/how-to-match-a-list-exactly-with-all-values-present-in-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no `size` keyword support. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords
- But you can add this method to repository and then service method without the size param
  `findAllByItems(List<String> items, Pageable pageable);` as it can pass the `items.size()` method internally

```
    @Query("Select d from DummyEntity d left join d.items i where i in :items " +
            "group by d having count(i) = :itemsSize")
    Page<DummyEntity> findAllByItems(List<String> items, 
                                     long itemsSize, 
                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this.

```
DummyEntity findOne(Example<DummyEntity> example); //repository
```

And in your service you can call it with following:

```
DummyEntity entity = new DummyEntity(List.of("first","second");
DummyEntity fromDb = repository.findOne(Example.of(entity));
```

Comment: I will test your answer at a future time, i do not know the term Example and seems usefull. Currently i am over my head with work... so postpone this one. My comment is marery to say that the answer below does not only check the size as you implied. I cannot for sure clarify how, but i run a dozen of unit tests (since like you to me it seemed as if it is based only on size) and it always finds only the entities that have the exact list items. I guess both me and you need to study little more sql. However it could be that your answer works and is more elegant so will check it out.

Comment: You are right, i didn`t read properly whole query. I changed my answer to avoid confusion.